# Minicart display 99+ after count exceed more than 99

Tags: magento2, mini-cart

How can I update minicart counter after qty exceeds 99.

Like, If customer adds `10000` qty to cart in minicart it will display `10000` which looks weird, So if total qty in cart exceeds more than 99 then I want to display 99+.

How can I achieve this? Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can read More about the knockout.js

(For quantity), Replace span counter number tag with

```
<span class="counter-number">
            <!-- ko if: getCartParam('summary_count') < 100 -->
                <!-- ko text: getCartParam('summary_count') --><!-- /ko -->
            <!-- /ko -->
            <!-- ko if: getCartParam('summary_count') > 99 -->
                <!-- ko text: '99+' --><!-- /ko -->
            <!-- /ko -->   
 </span>
```

& for items, replace counter label tag with below code.

```
   <span class="counter-label">
            <!-- ko if: getCartParam('summary_count') == 1 -->
            <!-- ko i18n: 'item' --><!-- /ko -->
            <!-- /ko -->
            <!-- ko if: getCartParam('summary_count') > 1 -->
              <!-- ko i18n: 'items' --><!-- /ko -->
            <!-- /ko -->
   </span>
```

Answer (score 2):

i think the easiest way to do this is to override `vendor\magento\module-checkout\view\frontend\templates\cart\minicart.phtml` and make changes in `<span class="counter-number">`. replace

```
<span class="counter-number"><!-- ko text: getCartParam('summary_count') --><!-- /ko --></span>
```

with:

```
<span class="counter-number">
<!-- ko if: getCartParam('summary_count') < 100 -->
    <!-- ko text: getCartParam('summary_count') --><!-- /ko -->
<!-- /ko -->
<!-- ko if: getCartParam('summary_count') > 99 -->
    <!-- ko text: '99+' --><!-- /ko -->
<!-- /ko -->   
</span>
```